# Android: make spinner item unselectable

Tags: android, spinner

I am writing an android application that has a spinner being populated with a string array with 5 items. Under certain conditions I would like several of these items to be un-selectable or disabled (greyed out and un-clickable). I found this article on google groups:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f6951f3340a6075a

this article explains how to create a PatchedSpinner class to accomplish this, but it does not explain how to use the class after it has been created. I am struggling with how I can create a spinner widget using this class. I would really appreciate any help on how to use this class, or any assistance on how I should go about accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 1):

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f6951f3340a6075a?pli=1

Not sure about the greyed out thing but these guys seemed to have found how to disable the spinner or at least being able to select the items.